# table data not wrapping

Tags: php, html

I have a table but the details column is not wrapping and the table is wider than the screen and it is annoying to use the horizontal scroll bar.  Any reason why this would happen?  How can I solve this please? My code is below.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards and thanks in advance,
Wesley

```
<table width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td class="row" colspan="3"><strong>Follow-Up History</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="15%"><b>Consultant</b></td>
        <td width="65%"><b>Details</b></td>
        <td width="20%"><b>Date</b></td>
    </tr>
    <?
        $mydb = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'elves');
        $q3 = "select * from clientcare.subcalls where callid = '$cID' order by `date` ASC";
        $r3 = mysql_query($q3, $mydb) or die("Query q3 died");
        while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($r3)) {
            $scConsultant = $row3["consultant"];
            $scDetails = $row3["details"];
            $scDate = $row3["date"];
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td width="15%"><?= $scConsultant; ?></td>
                <td width="65%"><?= $scDetails; ?></td>
                <td width="20%"><?= $scDate; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <?
        }
        mysql_close($mydb);
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You can wrap the table inside a `<div>` and give it a width of 90-95% width of your screen so that there is no scroll

Answer (score 3):

You should use CSS `table-layout: fixed;` property and apply `width` to your `table`

You'll see something like this -

without wrapping your `<td>` - [**Text doesn't wrap**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Avax/1/) (If the string is without any space )

else this is ok if the string is having spaces like this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Avax/3/)

but to be sure that your `td` doesn't overflow long strings

use the below properties to wrap your data in the table on `<td>` to wrap long strings:

```
table {
   table-layout: fixed;
   width: /* Whatever You Like */ ;
}

td { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

My [**final fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Avax/) (String With Spaces)

My **[final fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Avax/4/)** (String Without Spaces)

> P.S You can also fix `<td>` width's like this : **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Avax/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

Set `max-width`, otherwise the table will extend if it doesn't fit

```
<table style="max-width: 90%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong structure for last tr,**

```
<tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

**Correct structure**

```
<tr><td colspan="3"><hr></td></tr>
```